# cordova-plugin-chooser not working on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I’m using the Ionic Native Chooser plugin (cordova-plugin-chooser) to select files. It’s working great on android but on iOS the chooser opens, but all files are grayed out and I can’t select any of the files.

I don’t have specified any MIME-type, so the problem isn’t the file type.

What could I have done wrong?

Thanks in advance

Thilo